# jquery ajax synchronous call (execution on current thread needs to wait)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax to do a save, eg

```
$.ajax({

  type: "POST",
  url: "/service/save.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  async: true, // false is deprecated, do not use
  success: function(result){
    var split = result.split("##");
    if(split[0] == "exception") {
      alert(split[1]);
      ajaxStatus = 0;
    } else {
      ajaxStatus = 1;
    }
  }
});
```

my problem is that I need to wait on the current thread for the result before continuing.

I have tried using async:false, which works, but is deprecated, I need another way.

Also I have tried using a timer and callback like

```
ajaxWaitResponse(function() {
  return ajaxStatus
});



function ajaxWaitResponse(callback) {   
    if (ajaxStatus > -1) { 
      alert("SUCCESS");
      // we have a response
      callback();
    } else {
      // wait again
      setTimeout(function() {ajaxWaitResponse(callback)}, 1000);  // just a 1 second delay
    }

  }
```

But execution on the main thread continues past the callback.
PLEASE note, I need to wait on the current thread. 
I need to halt execution on the current thread without preventing the ajax thread from executing.

thanks in advance

Comment: Look at jQuery promises https://api.jquery.com/promise/.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What are you trying to do? What's your actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Rival seems like bad practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way of approaching this would be to use jQuery Promises. Something like this could work:

```
var ajaxRequest = function () {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/service/save.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (result) {
            // This will fire the done function
            deferred.resolve(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            // This will fire the fail function
            deferred.reject(xhr, status, errorThrown);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise();
};

var somefunction = function () {

    // This will return a promise
    var getSomeData = ajaxRequest();

    // The appropriate function will be called based on if the promise is resolved or rejected through the success and error functions in the AJAX request
    getSomeData.then(

        // Done response
        function (result) {
            alert("Success!");
            // Enter logic here to handle the data which you have waited for
        },

        // Fail response
        function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            // Handle errors here...
        }
    );
};

somefunction();
```

This method would also allow you to reuse the ajaxRequest function and handle the result in a different way if you wanted to!